# Date and username if clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tracker, the users add the lines to it on a daily basis. 
I need a code that shows the current date and username, once a cell is double clicked. Co column A would be a date cell and column P would be username.

I had some code but it shows user and date once a tick is done. Now I need a click.

```
Sub CheckBox_Date_Stamp()

Dim cbx As CheckBox

'Application.Caller returns the name of the CheckBox that called this macro
Set cbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

'.TopLeftCell returns the cell address located at the top left corner of the cbx checkbox
With cbx.TopLeftCell
    'Check the checkbox status (checked or unchecked)
    If cbx.Value = xlOn Then
        ' Checkbox is Checked
        ' User Name and Date-Time
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
    Else
        ' Checkbox is unchecked; Clear cell contents?
        .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Will you be able to help?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite tough to get what exactly do you mean, but in general, you need `SelectionChange` an event in worksheet. Add the following in the worksheet here:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = Cells(1, 2).Address Then
        Cells(1, 1) = Application.UserName
        Cells(1, 16) = Now
    Else
        Debug.Print "This was not B1"
    End If

End Sub
```

Once you click on `B1` you will get `UserName` and time in columns `A` and `P`.

Comment: Is this possible to change this so that it works when I click on A1 instead of B1? Would changing cells to (1,1) work?

Comment: @Adam - it will work, but you have to change also the cells where it is showing the username in the code.

Comment: ok, would not this be possible to show it in the cell that is clicked? I mean I click on A1 - and date pops in A1?

Comment: Then change `Cells(1, 2).Address` to `Cells(1, 1).Address`

Answer (score 0):

This will place the computer username and date/time in column A/B of whichever cell you double-click in.

Add the code to the worksheet rather than a separate module.
You may also want to add code to check that column A:B doesn't already contain data, or ask for confirmation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Environ("username")
    Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Now
End Sub
```